# Returning array when calling Fortran from Python using Ctypes

Tags: python, arrays, fortran, ctypes

How do you return arrays from Fortran to Python using ctypes?

As an example, I pass in an array (length 5) from Python to Fortran. An output array is created with the same values. Then, it is passed back to Python. Within Fortran, the values are correct, but after being sent back to Python, they are not. What about my setup is not allowing the array to pass correctly?

My Fortran code (e.g., test.f) contains the following:

```
SUBROUTINE mySub(inArray, lenInOut, outArray) BIND(C)

USE ISO_C_BINDING
IMPLICIT NONE

INTEGER(C_INT), INTENT(IN), VALUE :: lenInOut
REAL(C_DOUBLE), DIMENSION(lenInOut), INTENT(IN) :: inArray
REAL(C_DOUBLE), DIMENSION(lenInOut), INTENT(OUT) :: outArray

print *, "outArray from within Fortran"
do i = 1, lenInOut
  outArray(i) = inArray(i)
  print *, outArray(i)
end do
return
end subroutine mySub
```

This is compiled as a .so:

```
ifort -g -O0 -fpic -traceback -c -o "test.o" "../test.f"
ifort -shared -o "mylib.so"  ./test.o
```

Python code is as follows:

```
from ctypes import *

mylib = CDLL('mylib.so')

ArrayType = c_double*5
IntType = c_int
input1 = ArrayType(1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5)
input2 = IntType(5)
inputoutput = ArrayType(0,0,0,0,0)              

mylib.mySub.argtypes = [ArrayType,IntType,ArrayType]
mylib.mySub.restype =  ArrayType

output = mylib.mySub(input1,input2,inputoutput)

print '------------------------------------------------------'  
print 'output within Python'
print output
a = [0,1,2,3,4]
for ii in a: print output[ii]
```

The output gives the following:

```
#outArray from within Fortran
#1.10000000000000     
#2.20000000000000     
#3.30000000000000     
#4.40000000000000     
#5.50000000000000     
#------------------------------------------------------
#output within Python
#<__main__.c_double_Array_5 object at 0x10aa830>
#2.96439387505e-323
#6.91177308417e-310
#1.48219693752e-323
#6.91177308238e-310
#6.91177319086e-310
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple of things:

- Fortran uses call by reference, i.e. by default pointers are passed. However, by specifying `VALUE`, you switch to call by value instead. This you do only for `lenInOut`, so the correct `argtypes` are

```
mylib.mySub.argtypes = [ POINTER(c_double), c_int, POINTER(c_double) ]
```

- You have a subroutine here, not a function. So you do not get an output. Instead, your code fills the array `outArray`. The array `output` in your Python code is never touched and will print undefined values. As @eryksun points out, you might want to explicitly state that to avoid returning garbage from the stack / return value register:

```
mylib.mySub.restype = None
```

- Furthermore, you although you specify `bind(c)`, the name of the function is not exactly specified. If no `name` is specified in the `bind` attribute then lower case is mandated, cf. Fortran 2008 Clause 15.5.2 p2 (thanks @francescalus). To avoid this issue, provide `bind(c, name='mySub')`.
- Although you specify `IMPLICIT NONE`, `i` is not declared.

Further improvements:

- You don't need a `return` at the end of the subroutine.
- As the ctypes converter can handle Python `int` values, you can use `input2 = 5` directly (thanks to @eryksun for the hint)
- All ctypes buffers are initially zeroed, so you can simplify the initialization of `inputoutput` to `inputoutput = ArrayType()` (thanks to @eryksun for the hint)

---

The complete code then looks like:

test.f90:

```
SUBROUTINE mySub(inArray, lenInOut, outArray) BIND(C, NAME='mySub')

USE ISO_C_BINDING
IMPLICIT NONE

INTEGER(C_INT), INTENT(IN), VALUE :: lenInOut
REAL(C_DOUBLE), DIMENSION(lenInOut), INTENT(IN) :: inArray
REAL(C_DOUBLE), DIMENSION(lenInOut), INTENT(OUT) :: outArray
integer :: i 

print *, "outArray from within Fortran"
do i = 1, lenInOut
  outArray(i) = inArray(i)
  print *, outArray(i)
end do

end subroutine mySub
```

test.py:

```
from ctypes import *

mylib = CDLL('./mylib.so')
mylib.mySub.argtypes = [ POINTER(c_double), c_int, POINTER(c_double) ]
mylib.mySub.restype = None

ArrayType = c_double*5
IntType = c_int
input1 = ArrayType(1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5)
input2 = 5
inputoutput = ArrayType()              

mylib.mySub( input1, input2, inputoutput )

print '------------------------------------------------------'  
print 'output within Python'
a = [0,1,2,3,4]
for ii in a: print inputoutput[ii]
```

Comment: You may want to also set `mylib.mySub.restype = None` to avoid returning garbage from the stack / return value register.

Comment: You can also use `input2 = 5`; the converter handles Python `int` values. And `inputoutput = ArrayType()` since all ctypes buffers are initially zeroed.

Comment: Thanks very much to you both!

Comment: @alexander-vogt : I just tested you code under windows with `ifort` (for which, under windows, I did not manage to find an equivalent for `-fpic`) and add the error : `AttributeError: function 'mySub' not found`. Strange also : `dumpbin` shows me that there no methods exported in the dll ... Any idea ?...

Comment: @Olorin Dynamic libraries are handled differently than in Linux, but I'm no expert there. Sorry.